# PHP Writing in file russians letters

Tags: php, encoding

```
 $fp = fopen("tmp/$filename",'wb');
 fwrite($fp, $description, strlen($description));
 fclose($fp);
```

Hi. variable $description contains russian characters. After writing to file, these characters are displayed:

%u041A%u0430%u0436%u0435%u0442%u0441%u044F %u044F %u043F%u043E%u043D%u044F%u043B, %u043A%u0430%u043A %u0432%u0441%u0442%u0430%u0432%u043B%u044F%u0442%u044C %u0438%u0437%u043E%u0431%u0440%u0430%

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you really need to pass the length to `fwrite`.

Comment: Instead of all of your code, try simply `file_put_contents("/tmp/$filename", $description);`

Comment: Try to `utf8_encode($description)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encode them, with base64 or any other encoding, before writing them in the file if you only have to store them.